# How to adjust the Z-coordinate in bar3-function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have a matrix consisting of 8760 x 9 matrix of weather data from different years. For example here is a portion of my data: (each column represents different year)

[image]

What I would like to do is plot this data in 3-D as a normal line graphs so that I could nicely compare the data. When I try to do this with bar3-function I get this:

[image]

I tried to read the manual, but I didn't get it clear enough how to adjust the Z-coordinate. As you can see the data is "flattened" together...how could I get the different data sets more far apart so I could distinguish the different colors? Or should I use another function for this?...Just to clarify..this is what I would want to see (the image is from the guide)

[image]

thank you for any help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidently I found that `bar3(a, 1);` looks like your picture but `hold on; bar3(a, 1), shading flat;` looks good.

Code:

```
[b a] = meshgrid(1:9, 1:8000);
figure;
hold on;
bar3(a, 1), shading flat;
```